# Obj-C: Memory Leak of Malloc 6.00 KB in Core Graphics Library

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks

I am getting these huge leaks from this app and I cant seem to solve this issue.

The responsible Frame is CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData

Here are the leaks.

[image]
[image]

**EDIT**

The lines I believe are causing the issue

```
  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 49);
    UIView *myview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    myview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [myview addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-3.png"]]];
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 5)  {
        [[tabController tabBar] insertSubview:myview atIndex:0];
    }else{
        [[tabController tabBar] insertSubview:myview atIndex:1];
    }

    if ([UITabBar instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setSelectedImageTintColor:)]){
        [[tabController tabBar] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:189.f/255 green:224.f/255.f blue:2.f/255.f alpha:1]];

        [[tabController tabBar] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"g1.png"]]];

        [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:189.f/255 green:224.f/255.f blue:2.f/255.f alpha:1]];


        [[tabController tabBar] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hover.png"]];
        [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hover.png"]];

        for (int i=0; i<[tabController.viewControllers count]; i++) {
            UIViewController *tab= [tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];

            [tab.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                [UIColor colorWithRed:189.f/255 green:224.f/255.f blue:2.f/255.f alpha:1], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
                                                [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0,0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
                                                [UIFont fontWithName:@"Lucida Grande-Bold" size:10.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]
                                      forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        }
```

are causing this issue. I have been tasked to fix these leaks but need help fixing these ones. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that you've somehow managed to leak the whole tabBar or tabBarController, but not how you would do that (use UITabBarController in a property then assign to it, then overwrite it with another controller?)

Comment: @DavidH would it be because of the self.tabController. Should I refer to things without self in front?

Comment: No, but what does your property declaration look like? Are you using ARC? The lines of code you show are not problem as is, and thus the leak makes no sense yet given what you have provided.

Comment: I am using ARC and here is my property declaration `@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabController;` Check the updated code for a clear look at the issue.

Comment: No matter how I look at it, it seems like a bug from apple. Should be submitted on Radar.

Comment: You are using assign, not strong, for this property, and you put everything in an autorelease pool which releases all the objects - poof a leak. Look I know this is complex stuff, but you have to learn more of the basics before diving too deep. No reason I can think of for the autorelease pool.

Comment: @BigT Does the compiler warn you that you are missing strong/weak/etc in your property declaration? I don't know what the default is, but you should be specifying your IBOutlets as strong most of the time.

Comment: @benzado there is no warnings in the compiler. I believe the default is a assign.

Comment: @DavidH Even if I put strong in the property declaration or if I remove the autorelease pool the Malloc 6.00 kb object goes from 24kb to 30kb. I know the basics. I have done basic fixes before but since this project is in ARC I have assumed that everything would be released properly. Obviously not

Comment: The problem is that you mask the problem by doing the autorelease pool instead of minimizing your code to find the root problem. If you are leaking a huge chunk of objects at one time, they are probably owned by something. By using assign (the default) for properties, if you set the property with an object, then set it again, the first object is leaked, and that's probably what Instruments sees. So virtually all object properties should be strong unless you understand specifically why they should not be (special case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolating a leak is difficult in general; based on the comment-to-answer ratio I don't think you're going to get an answer on Stack Overflow.

I think the best strategy for this situation is to duplicate your project, then delete code until you can reproduce the leak with the smallest possible amount of code. At that point:

1. The solution will be obvious; or
2. You'll be able to post a more focused question here; or
3. It will clearly be a bug, and you'll be able to file a *useful* report with Apple.

You might also want to step back and see if there are unrelated memory problems. With ARC enabled, you might have "abandoned" memory: reachable, so not strictly a leak, but not used any more. [bbum has some good tips for using Instruments this way](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing things like addSubview and insertSubview, but nothing that removes.  Are you sure that you're removing the subviews as needed?  Looks like you're allocating additional objects and throwing them on top of the others.